# Closed form for a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence of positive reals satisfying the following recursive formula:

$$y_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3} \left(y_n + \frac{2}{y_n}\right).$$

Now, I am interested in finding out a closed form for the above recurrence, but am unable to do so. Here is what I have tried so far -

First, I tried using the method of fixed points. I solved the equation $\lambda=\frac{1}{3} \left(\lambda+\frac{2}{\lambda}\right),$ obtaining $\lambda= \pm 1$. Then, we can deduce the following:

$$y_{n+1} -1 = \frac{1}{3}\left(y_n-1\right) + \frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{1}{y_n}-1\right) \iff \frac{y_{n+1}-1}{y_n-1}=\frac{y_{n}-2}{3y_n},$$

and:
$$y_{n+1} + 1 = \frac{1}{3}\left(y_n+1\right) + \frac{2}{3} \left(\frac{1}{y_n}+1\right) \iff \frac{y_{n+1}+1}{y_n+1}=\frac{y_{n}+2}{3y_n}$$

Thus, we have the following:

$$\frac{y_{n+1}+1}{y_{n+1}-1}= \frac{y_{n}+2}{y_{n}-2} \cdot \frac{y_{n}+1}{y_{n}-1}$$

After this, I am stuck, especially since I can't seem to do anything with the expression $\frac{y_{n+2}}{y_{n-2}}$.

I also tried to use Generating functions but to no avail. Setting $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y_n x^n$, I only managed to obtain the following:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y_n x^n = y_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3} y_{n-1} + \frac{2}{3y_{n-1}}\right)x^n$$

$$=y_0 + \frac{1}{3} x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y_n x^n + \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y_{n-1}}x^{n} $$

$$=a_0+\frac{1}{3} x f(x)+ \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y_{n-1}}x^{n}$$

At which point, I have absolutely no clue on how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think that a closed form can be found ?

Comment: Hmm, is there a reason to think otherwise?

Comment: What would you do with a closed form?

Comment: Ok, here's some motivation - the original question was simply to provide an algebraic proof that if $1<y_n<2$, then $y_{n+1}<1<y_n+2<y_n$. Well, this wasn't too much of a trouble for me, but I just wanted to see if this recurrence has a closed form. In particular, I am intrigued why the method of fixed point seems to work much more smoothly for the recurrence $y_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(y_n+\frac{2}{y_n}\right)$, but changing the $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{3}$ seems to make the problem so much more difficult to tackle (that is, if I am not missing out something obvious! ).

Comment: Good progress . Yes, the factor of $1/2$ gives a perfect square $(y_n-p)^2$, however for $1/3$, we get a quadratic of $y_n.$ and we are unable to progress further.

Comment: Right, we indeed cannot get rid of the quadratic term. Thanks for the response!